# Terminology regarding a division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

The definition of a divisor goes as follows.

A nonzero integer $z_1$ is called a divisor of an integer $z_2$ (called a multiple) if there exists an integer $z_3$ such that $z_2 = z_3z_1$.

> I would like to know if there is any particular terminology for $z_3$ other than another divisor of $z_2$.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The dividend???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient  the dividend is z2 the divisors is z1 in this case and z3 is their quotient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that setting, the number $z_{3}$ may be called the (complete) quotient, where "complete" may be used to contrast the case where the remainder is $\neq 0$, in which case "incomplete quotient" may be used instead.

So "dividend = divisor $\times$ quotient + remainder".

For those who are not comfortable with "complete quotient", please refer to the appendix made by Bill down there :).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to formalise some number theory myself and was trying to avoid using the terminology "quotient" when there is no remainder. But I guess I could now call it the complete quotient. Thank you again.

Comment: @James Beware that "complete quotient" is very old-fashioned terminology that is rarely used nowadays. Instead, nowadays we say $z_3$ is the *exact* quotient of $z_2$ by $z_1,\,$ and $\,z_1$ divides $z_2$ *exactly*. If you use that ancient terminology then many readers will have no idea what it means.

Comment: @BillDubuque, If without context, yes.

Comment: @Gary Even with context. Where did you learn the term "complete quotient"?  I don't recall seeing it used in any recent publications (e.g. in the last 50 years, or maybe even 100 years). Can you give any cttations to recent usage?

Comment: @BillDubuque, no I can't recall.

Comment: @Gary Please post if you ever  do recall. It's possible it may still be used in some (old) elementary school textbooks. Occasionally I see some folks using old terminology that they learned from old books that were scanned and posted to Google books - not realizing that the terminology is no longer in use.

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you so much for making this so much clearer !!!

Comment: @James Btw, one way to gather usage statistics is to search Google Scholar, Books, and Ngrams, e.g. for "dividend" "divisor" and "complete quotient" or "exact quotient". You'll find some very old math in the former case (which highlights how much progress mathematical language has made in the last century).

Comment: @BillDubuque, wow very helpful thanks again!! Btw, based on your terminology of "exact quotient". Would "All exact quotients of integers by of which greatest common divisor are coprime" make sense?

Comment: @James Please give more context about what you wish to say.

Comment: @BillDubuque $\forall z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, if there exist $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $z_1 = a_1\text{gcd}(z_1,z_2)$ and $z_2 = a_2\text{gcd}(z_1,z_2)$, then $\text{gcd}(a_1,a_2)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In italian there is "quoto" for quotient when there is no remainder. It comes from the latin *quotus*. Not to be confused with the english "quota" (also italian "quota") from the latin *quota* femmine of *quotus*.